# Why I can't see a function "Data.Feature.setId(id)"? Google Maps JavaScript APIs

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I want to set identifier to a feature like this.

```
{  
  "type":"FeatureCollection",
  "features":[  
    {  
      "type":"Feature",
      "geometry":{  
        "type":"Polygon",
        "coordinates":[  
          [  
            [139.772865837, 35.703702135],
            [139.77279358, 35.703120198],
            [139.772866083, 35.703113532],
            [139.772906355, 35.70310964],
            [139.773296913, 35.703073532],
            [139.773325525, 35.7030710270001],
            [139.773376641, 35.703066306],
            [139.773661362, 35.703039919],
            [139.772865837, 35.703702135]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "id":"13101",
      "properties":{  
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

There is a function "Data.Feature.getId()".

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/data#Data.Feature.getId

**Question**

Why there is no function to set identifier?

And how to achieve to set identifer.

Comment: feature Id should be a unique value. ie, If you add another feature with the same Id, then It will update the first feature only and wont create a new data layer object

Comment: If you need such functionality, you can set a separate `property` called `id` or whatever else and then do `setProperty('id', 'value')` and `getProperty('id')`. That will just not be that `id` field you see. You could set your own `id` property to be that initial `id` if needed (`myFeature.setProperty('id', myFeature.getId())`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Google Maps API specifically, but generally in any programming language or model you don't set an object's id once it's constructed. This could lead to serious bugs. You set the id on construction (i.e. `new Something(<whatever id>)`) and then you only read it. If you want a new id, you have to recreate another object. That's what id is for. 
There never was another Otsuki Takaya nor will be. Same with Nelson here.

That's certainly the case here, because if you look to the constructor ([here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/data#Data.Feature.constructor)) you'll see it expects a `Data.FeatureOptions` object.
Looking in `Data.FeatureOptions` ([here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/data#Data.FeatureOptions)) you'll see that the `id` is one of the fields.

Comment: `id` is one of the fields but it is optional: *Feature ID is optional. If provided, it can be used to look up the feature in a Data object using the getFeatureById() method. Note that a feature's ID cannot be subsequently changed.*